# Pandas timestamp function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For a school project, I am writing a function that takes in a `datetime` variable. If the `datetime_variable.day_name() != 'Friday'` I need to subtract a day until the `day_name` is equal to Friday. I wrote what I thought was a recursive function to do this, however my loop never ends.

```
def getDateSplit(date_variable):
    
    from datetime import timedelta
    
    max_date = date_variable
    
    print('Max Date:', max_date, 'Day of Week:', max_date.day_name())
    
    if(max_date.day_name() == 'Friday'):
        return max_date
    else:
        return getDateSplit(max_date - timedelta(days = 1))
```

Comment: I need to set max_date to the very first date that has the day_name() == 'Friday' moving backwards

Comment: what kind of object is `date_variable`? I ask because I wasn't aware that `datetime.date` objects had a method `day_name()`

Comment: @L.Grozinger its a Pandas Timestamp object. Thank you, I'll edit the title now

Comment: @BlaineK, you may want to restart your python interpreter. The above solution works just fine (it prints out some intermediate values but returns the correct one on inspection), so it may be that you have "stale" variables in your interpreter environment

Comment: @anon01 I will look into that. I didn't even think to bother checking the variable after it ran. Thanks again. What interpreter are you using?

Comment: the interpreter doesn't really matter - python, ipython, jupyter - but if you define a function, then modify it, you can call the original definition if you don't have `autoreload` set up.  To be sure, the best way is to restart whatever you use to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimally adapted version will work:

```
def getDateSplit(date_variable):

    if date_variable.day_name() == "Friday":
        return date_variable

    return getDateSplit(date_variable - timedelta(days=1))
```

Example usage:

```
date_variable = pd.to_datetime("2018-01-01")
date_variable.day_name() # "Monday"

friday_before = getDateSplit(date_variable)

friday_before # Timestamp('2017-12-29 00:00:00')
friday_before.day_name() # "Friday"
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that cares, I went away from recursion. Not that cool yet. Here's my solution:

```
def getDateSplit(date_variable):

     from datetime import timedelta

     max_date = date_variable

     while(max_date.day_name() != 'Friday'):
         print('Max Date:', max_date, 'Day of Week:', max_date.day_name())
         max_date -= timedelta(days = 1)

     return max_date
```